# RML - Draw a red line with rml

Tags: rml

I know this post is a bit off-boundaries of openerp, but as rml is used in openerp, and my question could help others I write it here.

I would like to draw a red line in rml. I have already my line but I didn't see anywhere in the rml documentation how to set a different color for lines. Below is my actual line :

```
<lines>1.3cm 24.9cm 19.9cm 24.9cm</lines>
```

I have tried this :

```
<lines strokeColor="red">1.3cm 24.9cm 19.9cm 24.9cm</lines>`
```

But without success. Do you know how to set a color for a line object in rml ?

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<stroke color="red"/>
<lines>1.3cm 24.9cm 19.9cm 24.9cm</lines>
```

try it that way. all following lines will be red, so switch it back to for example black if you want following lines as black lines.